# Does Oracle Data Integrator completely do away with the need for PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, etl, data-warehouse, oracle-data-integrator

As an organization we are moving towards the purchase of ODI as an ELT tool.
We have plenty of PLSQL resource but I have heard ODI is powerful enough at data manipulation to replace much of what was previously done in PLSQL.

What are its strengths? And weaknesses?
And can it completely do away with coding the data transformation in PLSQL?

Comment: maybe this is really better suited for the ServerFault community, because it's less about programming but about "professional server/infrastructure soft- and hardware".

Comment: From experience... no. ODI will do what ODI does very well but it's not nearly as easy to customize as your code probably is. @MarcusMüller is correct, should be moved to serverfault.

Comment: ODI may well supplant PL/SQL **for ETL**, but for many many other tasks, PL/SQL is still required.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't however you might be 99% correct here.
It's actually a tricky question as PL/SQL might be submitted by ODI too.

I would reserve it (PL/SQL) for defining functions/procedures (if you REALLY need to) to be later called by ODI.
This should NEVER be something immediately related to ETL like INSERT INTO … SELECT … FROM … - that's where ODI fits the bill perfectly.

The only justified cases, I came across during my ODI experience (9yrs) were:
- creating PL/SQL function to authenticate (and later authorize through OBIEE) an LDAP/AD user
- creating helper functions to be later called by ODI DQ(CKM) modules like is_number, is_date
- creating XML files directly by DB (even with never ODI XML driver you might still find it's best to use native DB XML API/functionality to produce XML) - for performance reasons. Other direct file operations (load/unload) could be done in this way.
- creating my own (optimized) hierarchy traversal query for performance reasons (beaten the standard Oracle SQL 'Recursive Subquery Factoring' feature to about 1000:1)

It's up to you if you want to make a reusable piece of logic by using PL/SQL and call it from ODI or code it from ODI directly (in the PL/SQL form)